# Using GMP on windows

Tags: windows, gmp

I am trying to use GMP in a C++ program on windows, and I compiled it successfully with Cygwin, and I get an .a file, which is linux's version of a .lib file. Is there a way I can use this with the Visual C++ compiler, or is there a way to compile GMP for windows to produce a .lib file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about creating a .lib file, but you may want to look at [mpir](http://www.mpir.org/). MPIR is a fork of GMP that compiles with Visual Studio 2008 and 2010.